# Can I force a Delphi 6 TImageList bitmap to draw its transparent pixels as a certain color?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, transparency, ownerdrawn, tlistbox

I have a Delphi 6 application that owner-draws icons in a TListBox row along with some text. The `TListBox`'s Style is set to `lbOwnerDrawVariable`.  The problem I'm having is when an item is selected.  The highlight color used by the list box to change the background color of the selected row is making the icon look terrible because the icon has transparent pixels (my assumption based on the visible evidence), and those pixels are changed to the background color thereby ruining the image.  Is there an easy way to force the transparent pixels to be drawn a certain color so I can eliminate this problem?  I am using the `TImageList.Draw()` method to draw the icon on the `TListBox` canvas.

Comment: on your owner draw item method, you may draw a small rectangle with the brush color you want on the area to be covered by the icon just before you draw the icon.

Comment: @PA - I'd vote if the comment was an answer.

Comment: thanks, but in my opinion, this is not an answer to the OP question. It's a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Draw` method with `DrawingStyle` set to 'dsNormal' and setting whatever color you wish to use as the background to `BkColor`:

```
ImageList1.BkColor := clHighlight;
ImageList1.Draw(Canvas, 0, 0, 0, dsNormal, itImage);
```

If Delphi 6 does not have the `Draw` overload with 'DrawingStyle', then:

```
ImageList1.BkColor := clHighlight;
ImageList1.DrawingStyle := dsNormal;
ImageList1.Draw(Canvas, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The default `bkColor` is 'clNone', you can restore it afterwards for regular drawing.

Comment: @SertacAykuz.  Thanks for pointing out the mistaken DrawItem() reference.  I'm using the Draw() method and I've corrected my post to reflect that.

Comment: @SertacAkykuz - Your approach worked fine, thanks.  I had to use clWhite for the back color because clHighlight created the same "mottled" appearance that selecting the row did, but I know you were just using that as an example.  Note to others.  Obviously clWhite only worked for me because the bitmaps in my image list all use a light grey and white "background".  The correct BkColor to use will vary depending on your set of bitmaps.  Obviously if you have a bitmap set that a single  homogeneous BkColor will not work for, then you have a problem.